# iOS failed to compile Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I am developing two Xamarin Forms app with Android and iOS using Visual Studio. 
Yesterday my code was compiling fine, today I am not able to compile none of the two projects in iOS.

One thing I found rare is that if I want to debug I only have Device option to select:
[image]

and then if I try to compile I get the following message: 
"There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

Any ideas what could happened?
Really appreciate any help here

**edit: ** When I try to debug this is the log I get in Visual Studio:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AlutelMobile.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
1>  Generated session id: d9e05fdaaafe0ebd23e0c5641d5face8
1>  Generated build app name: AlutelMobileiOS
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You need to look at the error window to see what the specific build errors are.

Comment: @Jason There I updated the question

Comment: Keep digging.  If there is a build error, you should be getting a specific message about what the problem is.  Usually if you look in the error window (not the log) it will show the specific error, file, and line number.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded from Xamarin the last version available and install it on Visual Studio PC and in my Mac.

After that my physical devices and simulation devices showed up again.